# 8 million records query performance

Tags: mysql, sql, ssms, performance-testing

I have the query outlined as below. At present it takes over 8 min to run given there are over 8 million records within the `zt_Arrival_Data` table, while the `zt_Tpl_Tuple_Stats_2` tale only carries 9774 records, with the total output of simply 6946 unique records.

In what way can I structure this query to improve performance?

```
SELECT  distinct b.Tuple_ID
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(a.ORIGIN_CITY)) + ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(a.ORIGIN_STATE))   AS Origin_TX
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(a.DESTINATION_CITY)) + ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(a.DESTINATION_STATE)) AS Destination_TX
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(a.ORIGIN_CITY)) + ' - ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(a.CUSTOMER_NAME)) AS Origin_Customer_TX
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(a.ORIGIN_CITY)) + ' - ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(a.DESTINATION_CITY)) AS Origin_Destination_TX
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(a.CUSTOMER_NAME))   AS Customer_Name
    ,   LTRIM(RTRIM(a.CUSTOMER_NAME)) + ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(a.CUSTOMER_NO))  AS Customer_TX
    ,   CASE 
            WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(a.CUSTOMER_TYPE)) = 'C' THEN 'Customer'
            WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(a.CUSTOMER_TYPE)) = 'I' THEN 'Internal'
            WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(a.CUSTOMER_TYPE)) = 'S' THEN 'Shop'
            WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(a.CUSTOMER_TYPE)) = '' THEN 'zUnkown'
            ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(a.CUSTOMER_TYPE))
        END AS Customer_Type
    ,   CASE
            WHEN a.CARE_OF_NAME = '' THEN 'zUnknown'
            ELSE a.CARE_OF_NAME
        END AS Care_of_Name
    ,  LTRIM(RTRIM(a.ORIGIN_CITY        ))  AS Origin_City
    ,  LTRIM(RTRIM(a.ORIGIN_STATE       ))  AS Origin_State
    ,  LTRIM(RTRIM(a.DESTINATION_CITY   ))  AS Destination_City
    ,  LTRIM(RTRIM(a.DESTINATION_STATE  ))  AS Destination_State
    ,  LTRIM(RTRIM(b.BusinessGroup_TX   ))  AS BusinessGroup_TX
    ,   b.Fleet_TX AS Fleet_TX
    ,   c.Leg_TX AS Leg_TX
FROM         zt_Arrival_Data a
INNER JOIN   zt_Tpl_Tuple_Stats_2       b
            ON LTRIM(RTRIM(a.ORIGIN_CITY)) + ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(a.ORIGIN_STATE)) = b.ORIGIN_TX
            AND LTRIM(RTRIM(a.DESTINATION_CITY)) + ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(a.DESTINATION_STATE)) = b.DESTINATION_TX
            AND a.CUSTOMER_NO = b.CUSTOMER_CD
            AND a.BUSINESS_GROUP = b.BusinessGroup_TX
            AND a.[FLEET_ID (GEN PLANT)] = b.Fleet_TX
    JOIN zt_LegMap c ON c.Leg_CD = b.Leg_CD
```

Comment: Functions prevent index use,one thing you can do is create new columns from all those LTRIM concatenations ,at least for the columns in the JOIN

Comment: I'd check to see if you actually even need all of those `TRIM`s. I find that many developers just throw them in everywhere "because". If it turns out that your data really does have all sorts of leading and trailing spaces (trailing spaces should only matter for `CHAR` columns, not `VARCHAR` BTW) then fix the data rather then coding around bad data all the time.

Comment: @Mihai: you need to make that an answer so we can upvote it.

Comment: I agree with @Mihai and in addition I suggest to use as few functions as possible in query when you need performance. so remove all those `LTRIM, RTRIM` and you can handle them later on in php or .net or java, whatever you use for your project. or run `UPDATE` once to format your data. And the same to your `CASE WHEN`, update your table, set new column with value you need.

Comment: "Select distinct" on a query that has many columns with  several function calls and join involving funtions and concatenation = very poor performance only made worse by the "select distinct".

Answer (score 0):

It is far better to trim the data on data entry where it only has to happen once than to do this sort of thing against a large table in a select.

It is an especially bad design that you you have to concatenate in order to join. You lose the ability to use indexes when you do these things.  In SQL Server I would create a calculated persisted column that Ci could join on instead, not sure if mysql has such things.  But you should investigate doing this.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can only speed up bad design so far. You need to fix your datamodel and fix your data (while ensuring it won't come in needing trimming for the future.  This is something that needs refactoring to work correctly and the sooner the better. Let this be a lesson to you that no database should ever be designed by anyone except a data specialist.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I've learned that when you need to format fields in order to join the tables you should format the columns of the table which has LESS rows to match the one with MORE rows, which must be compared unaltered.

Some idea to start with:

```
FROM         zt_Arrival_Data a
INNER JOIN   zt_Tpl_Tuple_Stats_2       b
        ON a.ORIGIN_CITY = <format the b table columns to match a.ORIGIN_CITY>
        AND a.DESTINATION_STATE = <format the b table columns to match a.DESTINATION_STATE>
        AND a.DESTINATION_CITY = <format the b table columns to match a.DESTINATION_CITY>
        AND a.ORIGIN_STATE = <format the b table columns to match a.ORIGIN_STATE>
        AND a.CUSTOMER_NO = b.CUSTOMER_CD
        AND a.BUSINESS_GROUP = b.BusinessGroup_TX
        AND a.[FLEET_ID (GEN PLANT)] = b.Fleet_TX
```

Comment: I hope I explained myself, should you need a more detailed explanation I'm gonna need some example values of: 

`a.ORIGIN_CITY`, 
`a.ORIGIN_STATE`, 
`b.ORIGIN_TX`, 
`a.DESTINATION_CITY`, 
`a.DESTINATION_STATE`, 
`b.DESTINATION_TX`

But I might not be around in some minutes, so forgive me if I won't answer quickly.